# What do we know about the $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$-curve $X^{q-1} + Y^{q-1} + Z^{q-1}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, finite-fields, coding-theory, jacobians

People have thoroughly studied the Hermitian $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$-curve $H: X^{q+1} + Y^{q+1} + Z^{q+1} = 0$. What do we know about the similar $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$-curve $C: X^{q-1} + Y^{q-1} + Z^{q-1} = 0$ ? Could you give a reference in which I can find any information about it ?

Comment: I'm sure the jargon is common in algebraic geometry, but it looks strange to me to discuss "the curve $f(X, Y, Z)$", meaning, I assume, $\operatorname{Spec} k[X, Y, Z]/(f(X, Y, Z))$, instead of "the curve $f(X, Y, Z) = 0$".  Would you be amenable to an edit making the "${}= 0$" explicit?

Comment: The values of $x^{q-1}$ with $x\in\Bbb{F}_{q^2}^*$ range over the kernel $S$ of the relative norm map $N:\Bbb{F}_{q^2}^*\to\Bbb{F}_q^*$. My go to -technique to try and apply is the observation that with a fixed $\epsilon\in\Bbb{F}_{q^2}\setminus\Bbb{F}_q$ we have a parametrization of $S$ in terms of a variable $t$ ranging over $\Bbb{F}_q$:
$$S=\{1\}\cup\{\frac{\epsilon+t}{\epsilon^q+t}\mid t\in\Bbb{F}_q\}.$$
I'm afraid I don't know whether that leads to anything useful here? By homogeneity it suffices to study the case $Z^{q-1}=1$, reducing the number of variables, but even so...

Answer (score 8):

In [Rational points on some Fermat curves and surfaces over finite fields](http://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ezieve/papers/fermat.html), Voloch and Zieve study such curves and their points with coordinates in $\mathbb{F}_{q^i}$ for $i\le3$.

Comment: Thank you! What do we know about the Jacobian of $C$ ? How does it split over extensions of $\mathbb{F}_q$ ? In comparison, the Jacobian of $H$ is supersingular.